# C program halts after reading from socket

Tags: c, sockets, unix

My program reads from a socket in a loop and prints every receive. The problem is that my code prints everything to `stdout` right until the last `recv()` call, the one that returns `0 bytes`. After 2nd to last `recv()` the terminal I run the program in halts for a very long time before finishing execution, depending on the amount of reads (the more data, the more it halts).

I tried using `clock()` variables to record the runtime between snippets of code but the time is no different, even thought the last `printf()` takes ages to appear on my VM's terminal.
I've changed the code so the `path` variable does nothing, and the way I run it is `./exec www.google.com/randtext`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

void error(const char* msg){
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int socketfd;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent* he;
    char sendline[4096];
    char reciveline[4096];

    char* domain = argv[1];
    char* path = strchr(domain, '/');
    *path++ = '\0';
    //printf("host: %s;\npath: %s\n", domain, path);


    he = gethostbyname(domain);
    if(he == NULL){
        error("host error");
    }
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;     
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(80);
    serv_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)he->h_addr);
    socketfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&(serv_addr.sin_zero),8); 
    if (connect(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1){
       error("Connect");
    }

    memset(sendline, 0, sizeof(sendline));
    //snprintf(sendline, sizeof(sendline), "GET /%s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n", path, domain);
    snprintf(sendline, sizeof(sendline), "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n", domain);
    printf("%s\n", sendline);
    
    send(socketfd, sendline, strlen(sendline), 0); 
    printf("Data sent.\n\n");


    memset(reciveline,0,sizeof(reciveline));
    int total = sizeof(reciveline)-1;
    int bytes, i = 0;
    do {
        i++;
        bytes = recv(socketfd,reciveline,total,0);

        printf("Amount received : %d\n\n",bytes);
        if (bytes < 0)
            error("ERROR reading response from socket");
        if (bytes == 0){
            printf("\n\nbrokefree!\n\n");
            break;
        }
        reciveline[bytes] = '\0';
        printf("%s", reciveline);
        memset(reciveline,0,sizeof(reciveline));
    } while (1);
    close(socketfd);
    printf("Total loops : %d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In HTTP 1.1 connections are by default *persistent*, which means they are not closed immediately (unlike HTTP 1.0 in which connections are closed after each request, by default).

If you want the connections to be non-persistent you need to use the [`Connection: close` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection).